# Selecting Values from database using sqlDataSource And Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I have dates from a columon called Days_Class_On in a table called Session in a database called DataBase.mdf I created. I need these dates to be available for selection, after selection I need the selected Time to be displayed in profile page as booked appointment.

I used

```
        DataTable table = Class.GetAllSessions();
        GridView1.DataSource = table;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

I used GridView and sqldataSource but I get this error message

```
      System.InvalidOperationException: 'Both DataSource and DataSourceID 
      are defined on 'GridView1'
```

this is also the code in the design source code

```
           <body>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
           <div>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
         DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Days_Class_on"               
         DataValueField="Days_Class_on">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />


          <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
          OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"               
           AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Days_Class_on" 
           HeaderText="Days_Class_on" SortExpression="Days_Class_on" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <br />


               <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
              ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conn %>"              
        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Days_Class_on] FROM [Session] WHERE 
       ([Days_Class_on] = @Days_Class_on)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" 
         Name="Days_Class_on" PropertyName="SelectedValue"                     
         Type="DateTime" />
                  </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                   <br />
                 </div>
                 </form>
                </body>
```

Edit:  Extra Code

```
   public partial class test2 : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    DataTable table = Class.GetAllSessions();

    GridView1.DataSource = table;

    GridView1.DataBind();


  }

  protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }

    protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, 
   SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
  {

  }
  }
```

And here is the GetAllSessions Method

```
    public static DataTable GetSessionByName(string Session_name)
    {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = Config.GetConnectionStr();
    conn.Open();
    //Prepare SQL Command with parameter
    string sql = "Select * from Session Where Session_name = @Session_name";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Session_name", Session_name);
    // Create data adapter
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); //Create a DataTable that 
    will store the result of the query
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); // this will query your database and 
    return the result to your datatable
    da.Fill(dt);
    //Close connection and release the data adapter
    conn.Close();
    da.Dispose();
    //return the Datatable return dt; 

    return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Why you have `DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"` set on the GridView1 when you are setting the DataSource in codebehind?  I think you need to use SqlDataSource1 with Dropdown only to show distinct dates

Comment: When I remove DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" from the GridView1 I get this error                                                                                                               
            "    Data keys must be specified on GridView 'GridView1' before the 
                 selected data keys can be retrieved.  Use the DataKeyNames property to specify data keys."

Comment: Can you share the code of `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged` and `GetAllSessions` methods?

Comment: Ok I added it to the question